# lockers array program VISUAL BASIC

Tags: vb.net

I have to do a program in Visual Basic that displays the status of 100 lockers being either open or closed using a Boolean array. When the button `Initialize` is clicked, all the lockers should have a status of `opened`, but when `Simulate` is clicked, it goes through a process of closing every Nth locker (every 2nd locker, then every 3rd locker, then every 4th locker, and so on).

I have it working so that it always displays `opened` for every locker, but I can't figure out how to make it close every Nth locker.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1  
    Dim index As Integer  
    Dim doors(100) As Boolean

    Private Sub btnInitialize_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnInitialize.Click

        Dim count As Integer
        lstLockers.Items.Clear()
        lstLockers.Items.Add("Locker" & vbTab & "Status")

        For count = 1 To 100
            doors(count) = True

            If doors(count) = True Then
                lstLockers.Items.Add(count & vbTab & "Opened")
            End If
        Next

    End Sub



    Private Sub btnSimulate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSimulate.Click

        lstLockers.Items.Clear()
        lstLockers.Items.Add("Locker" & vbTab & "Status")

        Dim count As Integer
        Dim eq As Integer

        For count = 1 To 100
            doors(count) = True

            If doors(count) = True Then
                lstLockers.Items.Add(count & vbTab & "Opened")
            ElseIf doors(count) = False Then
                lstLockers.Items.Add(count & vbTab & "Closed")
            End If


        Next



    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The general form of the For statement is `FOR var = start TO end STEP increment`.  You were expected to remember to use STEP.

Comment: @HansPassant - If this is the case, I am way overthinking it in my posted answer. :)

Comment: As I understand PoppinWave's question, Hans answer is the case. (:

Answer (score 0):

In your `btnSimulate_Click` method, you are setting `doors` index to `true` and then immediately checking if it is true or not. This is why it always says `opened`.

Regarding closing every Nth locker, you can do this with a simple counter variable.

```
' n represents the "Nth" locker to close.
Dim n As Integer = 2
Dim progress As Integer = 0 ' Progress to n.

For count = 1 To 100
    ' This line shouldn't be here. doors has already been initialized.
    'doors(count) = True

    ' Increment progress towards n.
    progress = progress + 1

    ' Check if Nth interval is reached.
    If n = progress Then
        ' It is. Close the locker.
        doors(count) = False
        ' Increment n and reset the progress counter.
        n = n + 1
        progress = 0
    End If

    If doors(count) = True Then
        lstLockers.Items.Add(count & vbTab & "Opened")
    ElseIf doors(count) = False Then
        lstLockers.Items.Add(count & vbTab & "Closed")
    End If

Next
```

This would close lockers:

- 2 (n = 2)
- 5 (n = 3)
- 9 (n = 4)
- 14 (n = 5)
- etc.